# Is django.db.reset_queries required for a (nonweb) script that uses Django when DEBUG is False?

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, daemon

I have a script running continuously (using a for loop and time.sleep). It performs queries on models after loading Django. Debug is set to False in Django settings. However, I have noticed that the process will eat more and more memory. Before my time.sleep(5), I have added a call to django.db.reset_queries().

The very small leak (a few K at a time) has come to an almost full stop, and the issue appears to be addressed. However, I still can't explain why this solves the issue, since when I look at what reset_queries does, it seems to clear a list of queries located in each of connections.all().queries. When I try to output the length of these, it turns out to be 0. So the reset_queries() method seems to clear lists that are already empty.

Is there any reason this would still work nevertheless? I understand reset_queries() is run when using mod wsgi regardless of whether DEBUG is True or not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running a debugger, indeed, reset_queries() is required for a non-web python script that uses Django to make queries. For every query made in the while loop, I did find its string representation appended to ones of the queries list in connections.all(), even when DEBUG was set as False.